# Merging an odering objects in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i got 2 array of object, first one is the orginal one i got from API:

```
[{id: 0, name: "Weight", position: 0, visible: true, variation: true, options:["250","500"]},
{id: 0, name: "Pack", position: 1, visible: true, variation: true, options:["Card","Tin"]},
{id: 0, name: "Roast", position: 2, visible: true, variation: true, options:["Light","Medium","Dark]}]
```

second one is an elaborated one i rebuild based on selected option and looks similar to the first:

```
[{id: 0, name: "Pack", options:["Card"]},
{id: 0, name: "Roast",  options:["Light","Medium"]},
{id: 0, name: "Weight", options:["250","500"]},]
```

The second one is "shuffled" and missing some values in the object
What i am looking for is to merge the two array, based on object key name, keeping the options key/values from the second one, and the rest (position, visible, variable) from the first one, and then reorder the array based on position

At the moment i can only arrive to merge the two in a big one

```
function validateVariations(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.name);
    setSelected((selected) => [
      ...selected,
      { [event.target.name]: event.target.value },
    ]);
    const result = variations.filter((p) =>
      p.attributes.some((c) => c.option === event.target.value)
    );
    let newoptions = [];
    result.forEach((att) => { 
      newoptions = [...newoptions, ...att.attributes];
    });
    const myresult = newoptions.reduce((o, c) => {
      const exist = o.find((item) => item.id === c.id && item.name === c.name);
      if (!exist) {
        const options = newoptions
          .filter((item) => item.id === c.id && item.name === c.name)
          .map((item) => item.option);
        o.push({
          id: c.id,
          name: c.name,
          options: Array.from(new Set(options)),
        });
      }
      return o;
    }, []);
    const nemyresult = myresult.filter(function (obj) {
      return obj.name !== event.target.name;
    });
    const neattributes = attributes.filter(function (obj) {
      return obj.name === event.target.name;
    });

    Array.prototype.push.apply(nemyresult, neattributes);
    console.log('res', nemyresult);
    console.log('att', neattributes);
    console.log(attributes);
  }
```

attributes is the first array i show
nemyresult is the second one (and at the end i merge it with attributes)
the ne-something is because i remove (and keep back the original) from the object the options from which the selection came from

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: You have to post at least an attempt at what you have tried and what is wrong.

Comment: i tried a ton with no luck, i added the code of what ive done since now... but im stopped at the end and cant get out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the solution by using [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and array [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. First create key value pair by traversing first array using Map object. Then merge the two arrays using map method. At last, sort the array based on position.

```js
const a1 = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Weight',
    position: 0,
    visible: true,
    variation: true,
    options: ['250', '500'],
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Pack',
    position: 1,
    visible: true,
    variation: true,
    options: ['Card', 'Tin'],
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Roast',
    position: 2,
    visible: true,
    variation: true,
    options: ['Light', 'Medium', 'Dark'],
  },
];
const a2 = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Pack', options: ['Card'] },
  { id: 0, name: 'Roast', options: ['Light', 'Medium'] },
  { id: 0, name: 'Weight', options: ['250', '500'] },
];

const map = new Map();
a1.forEach((x) => map.set(x.name, x));
const ret = a2
  .map((x) => ({ ...map.get(x.name), ...x }))
  .sort((x, y) => x.position - y.position);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thank you! all this mapping, reduce and all are driving me nuts